# Reverse for ' ' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm getting this error anytime I click on this submit button on my listing page. I've looked through the typical places that this kind of error is triggered by but I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

**Error:**

```
Reverse for 'listing' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['listing/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

and further down on the page, on the traceback this line is highlighted as below. For clarity, it is highlighting the 2nd return render in that view.

```
auctions\views.py, line 229, in closeListing
            return render(request, "auctions/closeListing.html", {
```

I know that in my views and urls I pass the argument of id but then on the template I pass the argument of listing.id but this has been working throughout my project for some reason but just not working here. I actually just tried to change all the arguments in views and urls to listing_id to match the listing.id in the template and this produced the exact same error so I'm really lost.

**views.py**

```
def closeListing(request, id):
    bids = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).order_by('-bid_input')
    winner = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).latest('bid_input').bidder.id
    winner_name = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).latest('bid_input').bidder.username
    currentHighest = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']
    if request.method == "POST":
        if bids == 0:
            return render(request, "auctions/closeListing.html", {
                    "bids": bids,
                    "error": "No bids have been placed on your listing",
                    })
        else:
            Listing.objects.filter(id=id).update(status='closed')
            Listing.objects.filter(id=id).update(winner=winner)
            closed = True
            return render(request, "auctions/closeListing.html", {
                "bids": bids,
                "current": currentHighest,
                "winner": winner_name,
                "closed": True
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/closeListing.html", {
            "bids": bids
        })
```

**urls.py**

```
path("listing/<int:id>/close", views.closeListing, name="closelisting")
```

**listingPage.html**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user == listing.lister %}
<div>
   <form action="{% url 'closelisting' listing.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type=submit value="Close Listing">
   </form>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't think any of these snippets show the location of the error. It looks like it's probably in `closeListing.html`. It will definitely be somewhere you've used `{% URL 'listing'... %}` in a template (or possibly `reverse('listing',...)` in a view.

Comment: Thank you @RobinZigmond you were right. On the `closeListing.html` I had a link to return to the original listing using `{% url 'listing' listing.id %}`. Now I've deleted that link, the page loads fine but I am confused why that URL failed.

Comment: Presumably because `listing.id` doesn't exist or is `None`. Check the view.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, I was building a similar auctioning site. The problem is that I was trying to extend the previous page, and also, I was using an argument `auctions.id` while no auctions object created.
My code looked like below:

```
    {% extends 'auctions/listing.html'%}
    {% block bids %}
        {% if message %} {{message}} {% endif %}
        <h4> Top bid: ${{top}}</h4>
        <form action="{% url 'bids' auction_id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="bid"> Your Bid: </label>
            <input type="number" name="my_bid">
            <input type="submit" value="Place Bid">
            </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

By removing the first line, and changing the form action URL to `#`, it worked. Of course `#` is a test. I needed to add the auction object in the context of the template.